# Read text file from google drive

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I have simple text file in my google drive and it is publicly shared. When I read it

```
   InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
```

The following is read. I assume my file is google doc format. Is there anyway I can read it as a text or convert it to text?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name="google" content="notranslate"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-  
   Compatible" content="IE=edge;"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-
   scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/><style>@font-face{font-       
   family:'Roboto';font-style:italic;font-...……..
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive), using the [Files: export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export?apix_params=%7B%22fileId%22%3A%22your-file-id%22%2C%22mimeType%22%3A%22text%2Fplain%22%7D) endpoint and setting the ***mimeType*** as `text/plain`, you will be able to get the file as the format you want.

You can check the [Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java) to get an idea about how to use the API on Java.

Comment: Well. I also tried Java version of QuickStart guide. Stuck on the following error.  java.io.IOException: unable to create directory: /tokens